# Can pylint be used to flag unused global variables?

Tags: python, pylint

In my python script in VSCode, pylint will warn against unused variables in e.g. a function, but not in the global scope. Can pylint be configured within VSCode to flag unused global variables?

Comment: Explicitly run `pylama` and `pylint`. This is not a programming question though.

Comment: So can VSCode not be set up to flag unused global variables more or less as you type?

Comment: I am not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

OK, got it:

1. In VSCode, add the setting `"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true`
2. In your `.pylintrc` file in the root of your project add/set `allow-global-unused-variables=no`

Comment: Equivalently: Using `--allow-global-unused-variables=no` when invoking from a shell directly.